# Angular Moment Picker don't overwrite ng-model value

Tags: angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

I'm using [Angular Moment Picker](https://indrimuska.github.io/angular-moment-picker/) in my project. When it comes to edit page, ng-model value should be overwrite by data from API, howerver the values does not overwrite to moment picker ng-model anyway instead of bind the ng-model value with undefined. If i remove moment-picker it does working. Below is the demo for my situation.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/digitcode/rm51pubu/3/)

**View**

```
 <input name="time_of_time"
    class="form-control"
    placeholder="Select a time"
    ng-model="scheduler.timeOfTime"
    ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}"
    moment-picker="scheduler.timeOfTime" //Working if remove this line
    format="HH:mm">
```

**Controller**

```
myApp.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.scheduler = {};

    $scope.scheduler.timeOfTime = '11:10';

    console.log($scope.scheduler);
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem.

This comment help me.
https://github.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker/issues/92#issuecomment-263669991

From the link. There are 2 way to do it.
1. Using formatted string date coming from moment-picker attribute

```
<input moment-picker="ctrl.formattedDate"
       ng-model="ctrl.momentDate"
       ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
       format="DD MMM YYYY"
       start-view="month">

<!-- Use `ctrl.formattedDate` anywhere -->
Formatted date: {{ ctrl.formattedDate }}
```

2. Retrieving the formatted date using the Moment.js object
remove parameter from moment-picker

```
<input moment-picker
       ng-model="ctrl.momentDate"
       ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
       format="DD MMM YYYY"
       start-view="month"
       change="ctrl.setFormattedDate(newValue)">

<!-- Use `ctrl.formattedDate` anywhere -->
Formatted date: {{ ctrl.formattedDate }}
```

And in your controller

```
ctrl.setFormattedDate = function (momentDate) {
   // do you stuff.. and
   ctrl.formattedDate = momentDate.format('DD MMM YYYY');
};
```

I end up go with method 2.
Hope this help.

Comment: You might also want to read this issue. https://github.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker/issues/95